# Solr saving additional field when saving document

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr4

I am using solr 4.6.0 and latest built version of solrnet inside VS2012.
I have word documents which I save in solr via:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(tempFilePath)) 
                {                
                    var result = _solr.Extract(
                        new ExtractParameters(fileStream, id)
                            {
                                ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text,
                                ExtractOnly = false                                
                            });

                }
                _solr.Commit();
```

I want to add some extra fields like date, department... how to do this with solrnet?

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/ExtractParameters.cs#L76

Comment: It works! Can you post your comment as answer?